# Une œuvre étroitement associée au « 14 Juillet » ?

Tags: littérature, france, éducation, culture

Depuis [1880](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%AAte_nationale_fran%C3%A7aise) (l'année où « La République [française] adopte le 14 juillet comme jour de fête nationale annuelle »), y a-t-il une (partie d'une) œuvre en littérature dont il est de notoriété (en France), non pas uniquement qu'elle évoque, mais bien qu'elle soit étroitement associée, soit par son sens ou ce qu'on y relate, voire à cause d'un parcours académique français (bac) etc., à la fête du « 14 Juillet » ou, plus généralement, à la fête nationale de la République française, hormis les [textes fondateurs](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/Droit-francais/Constitution) et celui de l'[hymne national](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Marseillaise) (*La Marseillaise*) : le cas échéant peut-on préciser laquelle, expliquer brièvement pourquoi et en présenter un court extrait ?

---

J'ai trouvé un poème d'[André Frénaud](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Fr%C3%A9naud) (*14 Juillet*) et un autre de Victor Hugo (*Célébration du 14 juillet dans la forêt*) mais de 1865 (et donc sans doute dans un contexte un peu [différent](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic55565-hugo-celebration-du-14-juillet-dans-la-foret.html)). En voici deux très brefs extraits :

> Je bois à la joie du peuple, au droit de l’homme
>  de croire à la
>   joie au moins une fois l’an.
>  À l’iris tricolore de l’œil
>   apparaissant
>  entre les grandes paupières de l’angoisse.
>  À la
>   douceur précaire, à l’illusion de l’amour.
>
> [ André Frénaud, *14 Juillet*, ds. *Soleil irréductible*, 1943-1959 ]
>
> ---
>
> C’est le quatorze juillet.
>  À pareil jour, sur la terre
>  La liberté s’éveillait
>  Et riait dans le tonnerre.
>
> [ Victor Hugo, *Célébration du 14 juillet dans la forêt*, ds. *Les
>   chansons des rues et des bois*, 1865 ]

Comment: Deux pages de ressources pour axer les recherches : https://www.reseau-canope.fr/cndpfileadmin/pour-memoire/le-14-juillet-naissance-dune-fete-nationale/introduction/ ; https://litrev.hypotheses.org/tag/14-juillet ; parmi ces références il y a certainement le roman d'Eric Vuillard [14 juillet](http://www.telerama.fr/livres/14-juillet,147238.php)

Comment: Juste un ajout : contrairement à ce que pensent 99,99 % des Français, le 14 juillet fête nationale n'est pas la prise de la Bastille en 1789 mais la fête de la Fédération (sorte d'union nationale retrouvée) en 1790, au 1er anniversaire de la précédente …

Answer (score 1):

Pour rester dans le cadre de la question qui demande « œuvre **en littérature** », je dirais :

- Le roman historique d'Eric Vuillard *14 juillet*, 4<sup>e</sup> de couverture :

> La prise de la Bastille est l’un des événements les plus célèbres de tous les temps. On nous récite son histoire telle qu’elle fut écrite par les notables, depuis l’Hôtel de ville, du point de vue de ceux qui n’y étaient pas. 14 Juillet raconte l’histoire de ceux qui y étaient. Un livre ardent et épiphanique, où notre fête nationale retrouve sa grandeur tumultueuse.
>   Blockquote

[Compte rendu](https://litrev.hypotheses.org/795#more-795) d'un table ronde autour du livre avec la participation de l'auteur.

- *Ça ira (1) Fin de Louis*, est un spectacle écrit par Joël Pommerat qui se déroule de 1787 à 1791, « Sans être explicitement désignées comme telles, la Prise de la Bastille, la Nuit du 4 Août et les Journées des 5 et 6 octobre 1789 constituent des jalons importants qui structurent la dramaturgie du spectacle. » ([Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87a_ira_(1)_Fin_de_Louis))

[Une critique](https://www.thaetre.com/2017/03/23/la-revolution-selon-pommerat-avant-propos/) du spectacle.

Answer (score 0):

Indubitablement, la Déclaration des droits de l'homme et du citoyen ! Sauf si vous considerez qu'il s'agit effectivement d'un texte fondateur.

---

'La Déclaration des droits de l'homme et du citoyen de 1789 est un texte fondamental de la Révolution française, qui énonce un ensemble de droits naturels individuels et les conditions de leur mise en œuvre. Ses derniers articles sont adoptés le 26 août 1789'

Comment: [La constitution française](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/Droit-francais/Constitution) met la *Déclaration des Droits de l'Homme et du Citoyen de 1789* dans les textes fondateurs puisqu'elle les considère « en viveur ». Celui qui a posé la question a écrit : « hormis les textes fondateurs et celui de l'hymne national (*La Marseillaise*)  ».

Answer (score 0):

The 1938 movie "La Marseillaise" by Jean Renoir is describing the strong influence of the July 14, 1789, events in Paris on the French Revolution in the whole country of France.

The movie is interesting by its caricatural description, very much influenced by the atmosphere created after the arrival of the Socialist Government of Léon Blum in 1936. I have seen that movie only once, a long time ago, but I remember very well that at some point, a group of revolutionaries of Marseille are given a piece of advice by one of their leaders, who says "Camarades, ne cédons pas à la provocation", an utterly anachronic sentence.